# InvalidOperationException raised when navigating back to a view

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, prism

I've a child view (SharedView) that's shared between two parent views so I add it to each parent view through a Region like this

```
<StackPanel>
  <ContentControl cal:RegionManager.RegionName="SharedViewRegion" />
</StackPanel>
```

In the parent view's ViewModel I register the child view like this

```
regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("SharedViewRegion", typeof(SharedView));
```

When I run the application if I open only one of the parent views it works as expected but if I open the two parent views then I get the following exception

> An exception occurred while creating a region with name
>   'SecondRegion'. The exception was: System.InvalidOperationException:
>   Specified element is already the logical child of another element.
>   Disconnect it first.

I've been googling and this is the closer solution I found to my problem [InvalidOperationException occurs when the same view instance is added to multiple ContentControl regions](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=InvalidOperationException%20when%20the%20same%20view%20instance%20is%20added%20to%20multiple%20ContentControl%20regions)

But I'm using the prism navigation feature so I'm instancing the parent view like this

```
regionManager.RequestNavigate("ModuleRegion", new Uri("ParentView1", UriKind.Relative));
```

Can someone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing the following:

Add a name to the ContentControl that is hosting the region

Now you have to remove the region's content before leaving the parent view so in the ViewModel add the following code to the OnNavigatedFrom method

```
public void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationContext navigationContext)
{
  ParentView.MyContentControl.Content = null;
}
```

Note: You can access the parent view importing it in your ViewModel.

Now you need to add the content to the region by hand because you removed it before leaving the region. Here's the code

```
public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
{
  SharedView view = (SharedView)ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance(typeof(SharedView));
  ParentView.MyContentControl.Content = view;
}
```

Note: In this method you must add some workaround because the first time you open this view you'll get a System.InvalidOperationException because PRISM will try to add the SharedView to MyContentControl.

Here's a possible workaround

```
bool isFirstTime = true;

public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
{
  if (isFirstTime)
  {
    isFirstTime = false;
    return;
  }
  SharedView view = (SharedView)ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance(typeof(SharedView));
  ParentView.MyContentControl.Content = view;
}
```

You have to do the same work in all parent views that share the SharedView

I hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

You should directly add view to region instead of view discovery for this case. Give unique names to your parent views (you can use a counter to make up a unique name).

```
var region = this.regionManager.Regions["SharedViewRegion"];
var viewName = string.Format("SharedView{0}", this.countParent+1);

//Only add if it doesn't exist
var view = region.GetView(viewName);
if (null==view)
{
 //Use container to get new instance of the parent view.
 view = this.container.Resolve<SharedView>();
 region.Add(view, name);
 //Increment the counter as you added a new parent view 
 this.countParent++;
}

//Now activate the view
region.Activate(view);
```

Comment: with that approach I'll have the same problem because for the second parent region the view is not instantiated so null==view is true and when adding the view to the region I'll get the same error I'm getting now

Comment: You shouldn't get the error, as the new view would be added to the region with a new key, i.e. your unique viewName. What type of Region are you using to host your view? tab, contentcontrol, itemscontrol.. etc? Single view regions like contentcontrol can only show one view at a time.